# Sublimetext2 replace multiple words with multiple words

Tags: sublimetext2

I am new at Sublime. I have a XML file, in this xml file you can find hundreds of rows with the following structure:

```
...
<property name="caption" value="A"/>
...
<property name="caption" value="xyz"/>
...
```

How to select all values ("A","xyz") of the attribute "value" and replace those strings with some other strings given as a column in an other text file or excel sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the solution.

1. Select `value="` And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly to select all instances of `value="`
2. Press <kbd>></kbd> (right arrow key) so that cursor is to the left of word like this `"|something"`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> again, this will select all the words i.e `A` `XYZ`
4. Open the file from which you want to replace the words (they should be one word per line and count must be the same as carriages)
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in orginal file

TADA

Comment: how to skip over some rows they has also the attribute value, because I don't want to edit all rows who has this attribute?

Comment: to skip a match use Crtl+K+D. http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Comment: thx, and what can I do if the string I want to replace contains more then one word, e.g. "xyz abc"? How to select the whole string?

Comment: @StellaMaris use select quoted https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Select%20Quoted

Answer (score 0):

You can select the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to select next occurrence. Likewise select all occurrences and you can edit multiple lines simultaneously.

Comment: Please show me a working example, how to sleect "A" and "xyz" and replace it with "is not" and "working" simultaneously.

Comment: But that will only replace all those words with single input.